# Android sends GET instead of POST

Tags: android, post, get

I have a backend for my android app, which returns 404 on GET and json on POST. Now, I'm trying to do POST request using [this snippet](http://www.androidsnippets.com/executing-a-http-post-request-with-httpclient):

```
public void postData() {
// Create a new HttpClient and Post Header
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://www.yoursite.com/api/login");

try {
    // Add your data
    List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", "email@email.com"));
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", "qwerty"));
    httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

    // Execute HTTP Post Request
    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

} catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
}
}
```

Server however receives GET request. With curl POST backend returns json as expected. But somehow httpPost sends GET(!) request. What could be the problem? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Guys, before mark as invalid question, make an effort to think twice :) question doesn't need your *expert opinion*, it has answer now

Comment: You might want to check your attitude; after all, you came here asking for help. You don't have an answer, you have a hack.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok guys, answered my own question pretty quickly, may be helpful for others.

**I replaced hostname with ip address, and it worked!**

Comment: That makes no sense. Is your server misconfigured?

Comment: Agreed with 323go, that's simply not how HttpPost works. @Roman you have either have misconfigured your server, or your backend is broken.

Comment: @323go This seems stupid, but really has a reason - android sometimes cannot find ip address by hostname, not sure about the mechanism below it, but I remember that have seen this before